# Protect against PHP file attack

Tags: php, apache, amazon-ec2

Our server has been attacked recently and looks something like the following in the logs:

```
[Mon Feb 18 09:18:43 2019] [IP_ADDRESS] script '/var/www/ynm.php' not found or unable to stat
[Mon Feb 18 09:18:43 2019] [IP_ADDRESS] script '/var/www/71.php' not found or unable to stat
[Mon Feb 18 09:18:44 2019] [IP_ADDRESS] script '/var/www/wadre.php' not found or unable to stat
[Mon Feb 18 09:18:44 2019] [IP_ADDRESS] script '/var/www/vm.php' not found or unable to stat
[Mon Feb 18 09:18:44 2019] [IP_ADDRESS] script '/var/www/test.php' not found or unable to stat
[Mon Feb 18 09:18:44 2019] [IP_ADDRESS] script '/var/www/1q.php' not found or unable to stat
[Mon Feb 18 09:18:45 2019] [IP_ADDRESS] script '/var/www/1111.php' not found or unable to stat
[Mon Feb 18 09:18:45 2019] [IP_ADDRESS] script '/var/www/errors.php' not found or unable to stat
[Mon Feb 18 09:18:46 2019] [IP_ADDRESS] script '/var/www/q.php' not found or unable to stat
```

These attacks go on for hours sometimes and freezes the server.

How can one protect against this? (This is for an Amazon EC2 instance for reference)

Thanks!

Comment: Something like `fail2ban`.

Comment: You may want to try this question on https://serverfault.com

Comment: If `IP_ADDRESS` is always the same maybe just blacklist it.

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty common just use fail2ban and enable some jails like badbot. Those bots are inoffensive as long as you don't have big security breaches. Usually they scan for /admin or /phpmyadmin or pre-installed folders that's a good thing to change those folder's name.